# Shorter way of checking several arguments to same value in a if-statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there an easy way to compare several arguments to the same value?
To exemplify what I mean I have written this code which doesn't work, but illustrates what I'm looking for:

```
if ((arg1 && arg2 && arg3) > 0)
```

Instead of needing to write:

```
if (arg1 > 0 && arg2 > 0 && arg3 > 0)
```

Benefits would, in my opinion, be easier to read the code, and only needing to change one value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One neat trick is to stream all the arguments and use `allMatch` with the predicate you want to check:

```
if (IntStream.of(arg1, arg2m arg3).allMatch(x -> x > 0)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are `int` variables: you can use a stream:

```
boolean gt3 = IntStream.of(arg1, arg2, arg3).allMatch(i -> i > 0);
```

The same applies to `long` and `double`, which have special stream types.

Answer (score 1):

If this really is something you do a *lot* of in your code then you could introduce an extension of the `signum` concept with an `enum`.

```
/**
 * Extends the signum function to multiple arguments
 * <p>
 * If all signums are the same then that will be returned.
 * <p>
 * If any are different - return Mixed.
 */
enum Sign {
    Negative, Positive, Zero, Mixed;

    public static Sign get(int n) {
        return n < 0 ? Negative : n == 0 ? Zero : Positive;
    }

    public static Sign get(int... n) {
        Sign first = get(n[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
            if(get(n[i]) != first) {
                return Mixed;
            }
        }
        return first;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
Sign.get(arg1, arg2, arg3) == Sign.Positive
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to combine operator to check the condition as you want. A way to have only the number `once` can be :

```
if(IntStream.of(arg1, arg2, arg3).allMatch(arg->arg>0)){
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If readability is your primary concern, you can move the test to a utility method:

```
if ( allIntGreaterZero(arg1, arg2, arg3) ) {
    ...
}

public static boolean allIntGreaterZero(int... a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).allMatch(i -> i > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can user `Stream.of` to perform this :

```
if (Stream.of(arg1, arg2, arg3).allMatch(arg -> arg > 0))
{
    System.out.println("Passed (if)");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not passed (else)");
}
```

But you can create your own "structure" to use like this :

```
checkIf(arg -> arg > 0, 
        () -> System.out.println("Passed (if)"), 
        () -> System.out.println("Not passed (else)"), 
        arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

And here is the implementation of `checkIf()` used above :

```
public static <T> void checkIf(Predicate<T> predicate, Runnable actionIfTrue, Runnable actionIfFalse, T... values)
{
    if (Stream.of(values).allMatch(predicate))
    {
        actionIfTrue.run();
    }
    else
    {
        actionIfFalse.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use a variable as the compare value and then you dont have to change it multiple times.There exists no way such as you desire.